# How can I use ":" as an AWK field separator?

Tags: bash, awk

Given the following command,

```
echo "1: " | awk '/1/ -F ":" {print $1}'
```

why does AWK output:

```
1:
```

?

Comment: `awk '/1/ -F ":" {print $1}'` will **ALWAYS** print out `$1` or an empty row if input row is also empty, ***regardless*** of whether `"1"` actually exists in that row or not

Answer (score 585, accepted):

`-F` is a command line argument, not AWK syntax. Try:

```bash
echo '1: ' | awk -F  ':' '/1/ {print $1}'
```

Comment: Ignorant's question here: the /1/ part is to tell awk to only process rows (or records to be more precise) that contain the number 1 right?

Comment: @rantsh Awk syntax looks like `(pattern){action}`. If `pattern` (mostly a conditional statement) is _true_, `action` is executed. If `pattern` is not available, `true` is implied. Here the `pattern` is `/1/` which states _is regex `1` matched in the  current record `$0`_

Comment: As a sidenote, if you separator is comma, you'd want to add -v OFS="," parameter to awk, to keep it in the output

Comment: And how you can indicate this in a .awk script?

Comment: @JoanSerrano Look at the answer by Dennis below that does exactly that

Answer (score 84):

If you want to do it programatically, you can use the `FS` variable:

```
echo "1: " | awk 'BEGIN { FS=":" } /1/ { print $1 }'
```

Note that if you change it in the main loop rather than the `BEGIN` loop, it takes affect for the *next* line read in, since the current line has already been split.

Answer (score 74):

You have multiple ways to set `:` as the separator:

```
awk -F: '{print $1}'

awk -v FS=: '{print $1}'

awk '{print $1}' FS=:

awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} {print $1}'
```

All of them are equivalent and will return `1` given a sample input "1:2:3":

```
$ awk -F: '{print $1}' <<< "1:2:3"
1
$ awk -v FS=: '{print $1}' <<< "1:2:3"
1
$ awk '{print $1}' FS=: <<< "1:2:3"
1
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} {print $1}' <<< "1:2:3"
1
```

Comment: which is the preferred way? i assume the final example with the `BEGIN` statement would be the most correct (being consistent with the overall `awk` syntax).

Comment: @randomware all of them are fine. I tend to use `BEGIN` if I use a file to store the whole thing, while `-F` comes in handy with one-liners.

Comment: It must be said that there are subtle differences between the third case and all others. Example : `awk 'BEGIN{print split("foo:bar",a)}' FS=":" file` and `awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"; print split("foo:bar",a)}' file`

Comment: @kvantour good point. I just asked about it in [Why is field separator taken into account differently if set before or after the expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57586974/1983854).

Comment: Thank you! I learn best from clear examples.

Comment: @kvantour : while your statements are very much true, personally, i always explicitly set the splitting delimiter in `split( )`, especially within functions, instead of having it being at the mercy of whatever `FS` is at that very moment (unless i'm splitting an empty string to clear an array, in which case, it doesn't matter at all)

Answer (score 12):

You can also use a regular expression as a field separator. The following will print "bar" by using a regular expression to set the number "10" as a separator.

```
echo "foo 10 bar" | awk -F'[0-9][0-9]' '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 11):

`-F` is an argument to `awk` itself:

```
$echo "1: " | awk -F":" '/1/ {print $1}'
1
```

Comment: No need to quote colon.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use:

```
echo "1: " | awk  '/1/{print $1-":"}'
```

This is a really funny equation.

Comment: what does `/1/` mean?

Comment: Find a pattern. In this case "1"

Comment: Why is it  a really funny equation?

Comment: i think this trick only works cuz the value before ":" is numeric.

 echo "ab1: " | awk  '/1/{print $1-":"}' fails, printing a "0"

Answer (score 4):

There isn't any need to write this much. Just put your desired field separator with the `-F` option in the AWK command and the column number you want to print segregated as per your mentioned field separator.

```
echo "1: " | awk -F: '{print $1}'
1

echo "1#2" | awk -F# '{print $1}'
1
```

Answer (score 4):

AWK works as a text interpreter **that goes linewise for the whole document** and **that goes fieldwise for each line**. Thus $1, $2...$n are references to the fields of each line ($1 is the first field, $2 is the second field, and so on...).

You can define a field separator by using the "-F" switch under the command line or within two brackets with "FS=...".

Now consider [the answer of Jürgen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609552/how-can-i-use-as-an-awk-field-separator/2609565#2609565):

```
echo "1: " | awk -F  ":" '/1/ {print $1}'
```

Above the field, boundaries are set by ":" so we have two fields $1 which is "1" and $2 which *is* the empty space. After comes the regular expression "/1/" that instructs the filter to output the first field only when the interpreter stumbles upon a line containing such an expression (I mean 1).

The output of the "echo" command is one line that contains "1", so the filter will work...

When dealing with the following example:

```
echo "1: " | awk '/1/ -F ":" {print $1}'
```

The syntax is messy and the **interpreter chose to ignore the part F ":"**
and switches to the default field splitter which is the empty space, thus outputting "1:" as the first field and there will be not a second field!

The answer of Jürgen contains the good syntax...

Comment: it's not `awk` ignored it - `awk` reads that as one regex's boolean outcome ( 1 / 0 ) , then `numerically minus` a variable named `F`, then string concat with a single colon (`:`), which means the total pattern yielded true because it's a non-empty string, thus `$1` split by default space gets printed

Answer (score -1):

```
echo "1: " | "456:abc:515:xyz "
```

> ```
> awk -F: NF=/1/
> ```

```
      1    |  456
```

UPDATE : realizing how verbose my previous answer was