# field separator in awk script

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am trying to print columns in file which are seperated by `|` using awk.

File content:

```
 postgres  | psql                   |               | 2018-09-17 05:00:45.096491+00 |            | active
 test_user | PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | ***.**.**.118 | 2018-09-17 03:55:22.310569+00 |            | idle in transaction
 test_user | PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | ***.**.**.95  | 2018-09-17 03:54:58.638521+00 |            | idle in transaction
```

I am using below awk command to separate columns in file.

```
 awk 'BEGIN { RS = "|" } ; { print $2 }' vv.txt
```

Also refer to image attached which gives clear idea about issue.
I am not sure why data is getting messed up? Is it also considering space as separator?

[image]

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#User_002dmodified `RS` is the record separator, not field separator.

Comment: ok whatever you call it separated by "|", how can i print value which is separated by "|" as column

Comment: Those are fields. Use the field separator.

Comment: that is what my question is how to do that..

Comment: That is what my link was for. It goes to the awk documentation. You can search for "field separator". And read it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use ":" as awk field separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609552/how-to-use-as-awk-field-separator)

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

As was explained in the comments, you modified the record separator instead of the field separator.

**Solution:**

```
awk -F'|' '{ print $2 }' vv.txt
```

**Output:**

```
psql
PostgreSQL JDBC Driver
PostgreSQL JDBC Driver
```