# Why is field separator taken into account differently if set before or after the expression?

Tags: awk, gnu

The code `print split("foo:bar", a)` returns how many slices did `split()` when trying to cut based on the field separator. Since the default field separator is the space and there is none in "foo:bar", the result is 1:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print split("foo:bar",a)}'
1
```

However, if the field separator is ":" then the result is obviously 2 ("foo" and "bar"):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"; print split("foo:bar", a)}'
2
$ awk -F: 'BEGIN{print split("foo:bar", a)}'
2
```

However, it does not if `FS` is defined *after* the Awk expression:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print split("foo:bar", a)}' FS=":"
1
```

If I print it not in the `BEGIN` block but when processing a file, the `FS` is already taken into account:

```
$ echo "bla" > file
$ awk '{print split("foo:bar",a)}' FS=":" file
2
```

So it looks like `FS` set *before* the expression is already taken into account in the `BEGIN` block, while it is not if defined *after*.

Why is this happening? I could not find details on this in [GNU Awk User's Guide → 4.5.4 Setting FS from the Command Line](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Command-Line-Field-Separator). I am working on GNU Awk 5.

Comment: Seems to be related to my post what I have found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script  If variable is defined after the code block, it will not work with BEGIN block.

Comment: @Jotne interesting! kvantour's answer here will be a good reference on _why_ this is happening. Good to see you here again, by the way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is not inherent to GNU awk but is POSIX.

**Calling convention:**

The awk calling convention is the following:

```
awk [-F sepstring] [-v assignment]... program [argument...]
awk [-F sepstring] -f progfile [-f progfile]... [-v assignment]...
       [argument...]
```

This shows that any option (flags `-F,-v,-f`) passed to awk should occur before the program definition and possible arguments. This shows that:

```
# this works
$ awk -F: '1' /dev/null
# this fails
$ awk '1' -F: /dev/null
awk: fatal: cannot open file `-F:' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

**Fieldseparators and assignments as options:**

The Standard states:

> **`-F  sepstring`:** Define the input field separator. This option shall be equivalent to: `-v FS=sepstring`
>
> **`-v  assignment`:**
>   The application shall ensure that the assignment argument is in the same form as an assignment operand. **The specified variable assignment shall occur prior to executing the awk program, including the actions associated with `BEGIN` patterns (if any)**. Multiple occurrences of this option can be specified.
>
> **<sub>source: [POSIX awk standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)</sub>**

So, if you define a variable assignment or declare a field separator using the options, `BEGIN` will know them:

```
$ awk -F: -v a=1 'BEGIN{print FS,a}'
: 1
```

**What are arguments?:**

The Standard states:

> **`argument`:** Either of the following two types of argument can be intermixed:
>   file
>
> - A pathname of a file that contains the input to be read, which is matched against the set of patterns in the program. If no file operands are specified, or if a file operand is '-', the standard input shall be used.
>     assignment
> - An *<snip: extremely long sentence to state `varname=varvalue`>*, shall specify a variable assignment rather than a pathname. *<snip: some extended details on the meaning of `varname=varvalue`>* **Each such variable assignment shall occur just prior to the processing of the following file, if any.** Thus, an assignment before the first file argument **shall be executed after the `BEGIN`** actions (if any), while an assignment after the last file argument shall occur **before the `END` actions** (if any). If there are no file arguments, assignments shall be executed before processing the standard input.
>
> **<sub>source: [POSIX awk standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)</sub>**

Which means that if you do:

```
$ awk program FS=val file
```

`BEGIN` will not know about the new definition of `FS` but any other part of the program will.

Example:

```
$ awk -v OFS="|" 'BEGIN{print "BEGIN",FS,a,""}END{print "END",a,""}' FS=: a=1 /dev/null
BEGIN| ||
END|:|1|
$ awk -v OFS="|" 'BEGIN{print "BEGIN",FS,a,""}
                  {print "ACTION",FS,a,""}
                  END{print "END",a,""}' FS=: a=1 <(echo 1) a=2
BEGIN| ||
ACTION|:|1|
END|:|2|
```

See also:

- [GNU awk manual: Section *Other arguments*](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Other-Arguments) for an understanding how GNU awk interprets the above.

Comment: You've created a great piece of content, many thanks for it! Do you think it is worth indicating the reference to Other Command-Line arguments [I mentioned in tripleee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57586974/why-is-field-separator-taken-into-account-differently-if-set-before-or-after-the/57587802#comment101632200_57587025)?

Comment: @fedorqui I'll include it as it mentions `ARGV` and `ARGC`. It looks like a longer version of my short comment under tripleee's answer. However, I disagree with the last sentence: _Given the variable assignment feature, the `-F` option for setting the value of FS is not strictly necessary. It remains for historical compatibility._. Using `-F` can be necessary when using `getline` in a `BEGIN` statement, but you can also define `FS` there.

Answer (score 3):

Because you can set the variable individually for each file you process, and `BEGIN` happens before any of that.

```
bash$ awk '{ print NF }' <(echo "foo:bar") FS=: <(echo "foo:bar")
1
2
```

Comment: So `-F` happens before the `BEGIN` block and `FS=:` (on the right) happens before the `BEGINFILE` block but after the `BEGIN`?

Comment: Quite so, yes. Options are handled before `BEGIN`, non-option arguments after.

Comment: @fedorqui exactly. The flag `-F` is processed by awk as a flag and not as an argument which is located in `ARGV`. Anything located in `ARGV` is processed after `BEGIN`. `BEGINFILE` has no effect on that. Awk will process an element of `ARGV` in the following way. If it is a file, it will run `BEGINFILE`, if it is a variable assignement, it will assign the definition. As a consequence, it will do so before `BEGINFILE`.

Comment: @kvantour aaah that's it! In [2.3 Other Command-Line Arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Other-Arguments) _The distinction between file name arguments and variable-assignment arguments is made when awk is about to open the next input file. At that point in execution, it checks the file name to see whether it is really a variable assignment; if so, awk sets the variable instead of reading a file_ and then _the values of variables assigned in this fashion are not available inside a BEGIN rule_.

Comment: @fedorqui also be aware that this works : `awk -F: '1' /dev/null`, but this does not `awk '1' -F: /dev/null`